# Endomorphisms of a vector bundle on an elliptic curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, vector-bundles

Let $E$ be an elliptic curve over a field $k = \mathbb{C}$ and $B$ is an indecomposable vector bundle over $E$. Is it true that $End(B)=k$?

Comment: No. Elliptic curve has rank two indecomposable vector bundle $B$ which fits into a non-split exact sequence $0\to O\to B\to O\to 0$, using the fact that $H^1(O)=k$. But $B$ has a nilpotent non-zero endomorphism, seen from the above exact sequence.

Comment: Okay, but how can we see this? From that sequence we have that $H^0(B) = H^1(B)=k$ and $B^*\cong B$. To compute $End(B)$ we tensor this exact sequence with $B$ and take the long exact sequence of cohomologies. Then everything boils down to whether the connecting map $\delta: H^0(B)\to H^1(B)$ is zero or not. How can I show that it is actually zero?

Comment: So, the endomorphism is given by an injection of $O$ into $B$ and a surjection of $B$ onto $O$?

Comment: Take the surjection from $B\to O$ and compose with the injection $O\to B$ to get an endomorphism of $B$, whose square is zero.